# C++: Optimal way to replace control characters in a string

Tags: c++

For a parsing job, I have a string that can be essentially anything. 
'
For instance:

```
"something \t \n \0 \whatever else"
```

---

At the end of the parse, I need to serialize the output to easy-to-work with JSON...which means I need to get rid of the control characters.  For all value entries, I run a string sanitizer:

```
void sanitizer(std::string & value){
   for (auto& it : value){
     if ((int) sit <= 31 || (int) sit == 127){
        if (sit == '\t')
            std::cout << "\\t";
        else if (sit == '\r')
            std::cout << "\\r";
        else if (sit == '\0')
            std::cout << "\\0";
        else if (sit == '\n')
            std::cout << "\\n";

        else 
            std::cout << " ";
      } else if (sit == '"'){
          std::cout << '\'';
      } else if (sit == '\\')
          std::cout << "/";
      else 
          std::cout << sit;
    }
```

However, this function, alone, occupies about 44% of the time in the parser.

When I eliminate the `std::cout` calls, and instead build a string, then print to `cout`, this slows things down further.

---

Is there an optimized way to replace/escape these control characters in a string with C++?

Comment: I would suspect that writing to `cout` one character at a time, while perhaps not _terrible_, is also not great. Maybe try filling an output buffer (array) and output the whole lot when it fills.

Comment: @davmac thanks man.  treeing out the if statements as well.  Think there are a couple issues with them as well.

Comment: Wouldn't a `switch` statement make more sense?

Comment: @Rotem yeah, was going to do that.  However, would it be compiled differently?

Comment: @bordeo Not sure if compilers tend to auto-optimize a long `elif` into a `switch`.

Comment: @bordero Either way, make sure you are profiling with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @Rotem I think I might not have been doing that.

Comment: replace `std::cout` with a `std::string_stream ss;`, and then `std::cout << ss.str()` when you are done

Comment: Or just use json-c, maybe? And there's `isprintable()`. You can convert everything else to unicode literal.

Comment: i'd be surprised if it was spending 44% of its time replacing characters. Perhaps it's spending time in the multiple calls to cout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `std::iscntrl` function along with `std::remove_if`:

```
void remove_control_characters(std::string& s) {
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return std::iscntrl(c); }), s.end());
}
```

Further improvement would be to implement your own character classification function. `std::iscntrl` uses the current global locale object for that.

Comment: @bordeo Note that this function does not replace the control characters, rather removes them.

Comment: thanks--yeah, I may not be using `s.erase`, depending on my specific case.  But, I think it gets at the heart of the problem: detecting the control characters with `std::iscntrl`; but, having read my question prompt, I'll accept an answer that replaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like below work for your purposes?

```
void sanitizer(std::string & value) {
    std::string prev_loc = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr);
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.iso88591");
    std::replace_if(value.begin(), value.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::iscntrl(c); }, ' ');
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, prev_loc.c_str());
}
```